# Joomla 3.4.3 - configuration.php not writable

Tags: php, apache, joomla, configuration, redhat

Using MariaDB, Apache, PHP 5.4.x, RHEL 7

How do I allow configuration.php to be written to?

Installed Joomla several times, always ending up with the configuration.php file not writable.  I proceeded, copied the config content and created a new php file, placed it where Joomla lives, opened up the permissions, changed to apache:apache, still nothing.   I've referenced several articles, notably this one: 
[Installing Joomla 3 Error: Your configuration file or directory is not writable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080877/installing-joomla-3-error-your-configuration-file-or-directory-is-not-writable?s=1|1.4723)

I have also tried creating an empty configuration.php file and placing it in the joomla root, opening up permissions - didnt work.

My current state of installation is configuration.php file in place, but unable to remove the installation directory via the web installer (assuming because I shoehorned the config file into place and still not being writable).

I've tried several permissions setups then attempting to remove the install directory without success.  Manually removing the install directory via rm -r only yields a totally inaccessible site forcing me to wipe my joomla files, databases, and install again. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with my server guy - found out that several sebool settings were keeping Apache from doing what it needed to do.  Going one step further, we identified that sebool commands needed to be ran to allow httpd_can_sendmail in order to use the Sendmail feature.  Hope this helps someone out there.

The command that seemed to do the trick was ***sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html***

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do is check what user php runs at on your server, and compare this with ownership of your site files.

Create user.php file at the root of your domain with

```
<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>
```

then open that file with your broser. This will give you the name of the user that php runs as on your server. It may be apache but it may not.

Compare this user with the ownership of config.php and your site installation as a whole.

If you upload a new Joomla site via SFTP and follow the standard browser instal steps, permissions shouldn't be a problem. If you are say uploading a zip file and using a terminal connection and SSH, make sure your SSH connection is the same user as the php user on your server.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In our case, problem was with CentOS permissions. So if Joomla is installed on CentOS powered server, you need to change config file (/etc/selinux/config) to look like this:

```
[root@host2a ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/selinux
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=permissive
# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#       targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#       strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted

# SETLOCALDEFS= Check local definition changes
SETLOCALDEFS=0
```

Actually, you only set SELINUX to permissive.

Hope this helps.

p.s. Solution works for RedHat too.